# TypeScript - How to access dictionary value by key?

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
options: { language: string; value: { parameterId: string; parameterValue: string } }[];
```

When I inspect an instance of this at runtime, it looks like this:

```
{de: Object, en: Object}
de:{1: "-", 2: "grün", 3: "gelb", 4: "rot" }
en:{1: "-", 2: "green", 3: "yellow", 4: "red" }
__proto__:{}
```

I am now trying to write a function which returns one of those dictionaries depending on these rules:

1. If there is an entry with key "-", return this entry.
2. Else if there is an entry with the current browser language as key, return it.
3. Else if there is an entry with key "en", return it.
4. Else return an empty dictionary.

This is my first attempt to write this function:

```
filterOptions(
  options: { language: string; value: { parameterId: string; parameterValue: string } }[],
) {
  const languageIndependentKey = "-";

  if (languageIndependentKey in options) {
    return options[languageIndependentKey];
  }
  if (this.translate.currentLang in options) {
    ...
  } else if ("en" in options) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

This does not seem to work because I get the following error in the line `return options[languageIndependentKey];`:

```
error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

I simply cannot figure out how to write this function without causing this error. How can I check if a specific key is present in the dictionary and return the corresponding dictionary at that key? I can't imagine that this is so difficult, but everything I tried so far did not work.

For some reason, this code runs just fine:

```
for (const language in options) {
  return options[language];
}
```

But directly accessing an entry like `options["en"]` causes an error. Why? Is my declaration of the dictionary type incorrect, or what is going on here?

Comment: Your "dictionary of dictionaries" is not matching the structure of the actual data you have. It looks like you have a dictionary of array-like things which just hold strings and not key-value pairs. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBjndN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following interface. Swap it with your code, in case everything else is structured properly.

```
{
 language: string,      
 [key: string]: {
 parameter
  .....
}
```

Also you have wrong type next to parameter, it should be number from what I see.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, your type wasn't the correct one for dictionary of dictionaries.

If you look at the ParameterOptions type, it is a dictionary keyed by string, with a value of a dictionary keyed by number.

Your code appears as if you intended for a dictionary keyed by string, with a dictionary inside that also keyed by string.

While I'm guessing you are happy with the solution you found, just remember that in typescript, your dictionary should look like
`{ [key: string]: string }`  and your dictionary of dictionaries should look like
`{ [key: string]: { [key: string]: string }`

```
function filterOptions(options: { [language: string]: { [parameterId: string]: string } } )  {
  const languageIndependentKey = "-";

  if (options.hasOwnProperty(languageIndependentKey)) {
    return options[languageIndependentKey]
  }  else if (options.hasOwnProperty( translate.currentLang)) {
    return options[translate.currentLang];
  } else if (options.hasOwnProperty("en")) {
    return options["en"];
  } else {
    throw new Error("Unable to locate filter option");
  }
}


[TypeScript Playground Link][1]


  [1]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCmMC8MDewArvPBmFADLIDmAXDAEQBWA1gwL4DcAUNwGaEwwKAEtwMPiJSZ4AeQAOo8BAAUIRWMj08MANpow1QomoZ60eCMMBdbXvmIkAWwwyAkgBNzCK9VswLXxh2YJgAShh8bkjQSFgDIxMMNzAPDHkyNPIAaQwATxxGAFoGHmiYET4YNQ1lADoAC0QIWQB3MAAFeHUMeCg8lQTjUxS0jNSyKFy8sIi8csjSKGIwGHUlSH0aYeSJ8ayp-OtykJgMFAgsSur1zQhG5rbO7oy%20gbgkVHQMOqISSaohlmUUii1cKzWtU2CGQEDQmF%20xFI5EBfh4kRC50uFSqNQ29yaLXaXR6bxUDDIDGB81BMCWENuyl0FLADGs6NCWKwNNBUAa3VaMDAGEFAFESCB4OSAKpgRAAIxQWCgIBgKBAwG%20EikMkhGypHPY3CNsQgICVvyVjhUYTK3FNsEZWnweiGSW8lhsdl0Dmcrl6ng9vn8gUMoRCuHmLIY2jlLnoDDjGAYABoYE5kAmM6z2CnuBSIDH8EmE2AQE55aRU%20nM4wGuXK8ngsayqbzT91dQVJJpL0FPi8Xcwszs2zbbwYV8EX9kZQaIUC6VeG2LZ3uzq%201DVE6IMOGKPrOPuDvmSVrIUdCXGAAxQgoFAwAByiBc1ezCYAsvAP8gOK3lO2dRrj2Mj9ncg7KHuB5HpOcLfIi-wovOuDRjwaRKpgep3HUZBoec-pYUyDBnv%20kCAcBG5yFuEGQFBv6HpwQA
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem myself by using the type `ParameterOptions` which is defined as follows:

```
export class ParameterOptions {
  [language: string]: { [parameterId: number]: string };
}
```

Comment: Nice one, at least it was useful to give you clue.